# How to see controllers response?

Tags: control-systems

How can I get/plot the controller's effort of a controlled system (state space model)?

Example system:

```
matA = {{0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {-50.67, -50.67, -4.9, 
    4.9, -0.00226}, {25.25, -25.25, 2.44, -2.44, 0}, {-6400000, 0, 
    210000, 0, -3.26}};
matB = {{0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {-1440}};
matC = {1, 0, 0, 0, 0};
xVec0 = {{5}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}};

ssm = StateSpaceModel[{matA, matB, {matC}, {{0}}}]
```

[image]

Find the state feedback gains:

```
eigSys = Eigenvalues[matA];
eigSysStable = eigSys;
eigSysStable[[3]] = -eigSysStable[[3]];
ctrl = StateFeedbackGains[ssm, eigSysStable];
ssmCtrl = SystemsModelStateFeedbackConnect[ssm, ctrl]
```

[image]

Now I can plot my state responses (or output)

```
t0 = 0;
tMax = .5;

srSys = StateResponse[{ssmCtrl, xVec0}, 0, {t, t0, tMax}];
Plot[{srSys[[1]], srSys[[5]]/10^5}, {t, t0, tMax}, PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotLegends -> {"x1", 
   "x5 (*\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(10\), \(-5\)]\))"}]
```

[image]

But how can I access and plot what the controller does? The "ControllerResponse"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is state feedback, the control effort is  $-(statefeedbackgains).(state response)$

```
Plot[-ctrl.srSys, {t, t0, tMax}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Suba, I just wondered if there's a build-in function for this. But can you explain why you're using the negative? Just asking because in my documents it's positive.

Comment: Phab, I think this computation is trivial to warrant a separate function. But there are cases where this computation is not straightforward and can be done with the help of properties: http://wolfram.com/xid/0dbi23tfa58uxj73eu-8cc9y, https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-10/nonlinear-control-systems/feedback-linearization.html

Comment: In answer to your second question, there is no hard and fast rule about the sign convention. We have chosen negative feedback and tried to be consistent throughout (e.g., you can give the gains directly to SystemsModelStateFeedbackConnect which also assumes negative feedback by default). This is also the convention followed by Ogata, Nise, and Franklin, Powell & Emami-Naeini among others.